# How to dynamically allocate 2D aligned array?

Tags: c, arrays, alignment, 2d, dynamic-memory-allocation

I need a way to represent 2d images by 2d arrays. Currently, I'm using the following implementation to initialize an image with zero-valued pixels:

```
float **data = (float**)malloc(rows*sizeof(float*));
data[0] = (float*)calloc(rows*cols,sizeof(float));
for(unsigned i=1; i<rows; i++)
    data[i] = data[i-1]+cols;
```

It allocates an array of pointers, and then allocates an array of zeros in the first element. Other elements just point to the rows of the array. This is very efficient because I have actually 1d array (which is cache friendly) and at the same time can use 2d index [][] to get the value of pixels.

How can I change the above code to posix_memalign or other similar aligned allocation functions?

Comment: This seems to be a C-Question. In C++ malloc and calloc are not used. If you change the tag from C++ to C, you will maybe get answers

Comment: @TarekDakhran
I had seen that question before. I need initializing to zero.

Comment: You can use [memset](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/)  for that.

Comment: Thanks. I used that link with memset and It compiles and runs. My goal to use posix_memalign was to benefit from GCC auto-vectorization. But I can't see any speedup in my code. I have also read that malloc itself handles alignment. Is that true? If yes, why there is posix_memalign? I have seen that OpenCV Library uses posix_memalign:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp#L126